# Derived class.I want to cout the "Base" variables of a derived class object

Tags: c++

So i have overloaded both base and derived class the <<  operator with the help of a virtual member function like that

```
        class Person
        {    
        protected:
                string name;
                size_t age;
                virtual void print(ostream& out)  const;
            public:
                friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Person& rhs);{rhs.print(out); return out;}
        };

        class Doctor : public Person
        {
        private:
            string hospital;
            vector<Patient*> patients;
            void print(ostream& out)  const override;{
                  out << "Doctor: " << name << " " << age << " " << "Hospital: " << hospital
            } ;
        public: 
        };
```

Now i just want to output name and age (Person variables only) not hospital.If I type this

```
Doctor a;
cout <<a;
```

i get hospital as well.
Any way to do this? (Has to do anything with scope resolution or something?)

P.S. costructors are all made i just didn't include them here so the code is smaller

Comment: Remove `<< "Hospital: " << hospital` from `print()` in the derived class. `operator<<` invokes the `override`-d `print()` function of the derived class.

Comment: So the code is a small part of a bigger app so sometimes i need to outpout the hospital as well. I want to know if there is a way to output the Person variables o a Doctor.

Comment: That's pretty much an issue with your design. You made `print` function polymorphic (aka. `virtual`), so the compiler will always treat it in polymorphic way and look up the correct derided method to call. At this point you cannot choose which `print()` will be called - compiler selects it depending on runtime type information.

Comment: Do you want `a.Person::Print(std::cout)` (ignoring access issue)?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the behavior is what you explicitly asked for, as `print` is virtual. If you want to control whether to call the `Doctor` or `Person` overload of `operator<<` you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Person {
    virtual ~Person(){}
};
struct Doctor : Person {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const Person&) {
    return out << "I am a person\n";
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const Doctor&) {
    return out << "I am a doctor\n";
}

int main() {
    Doctor d;
    std::cout << d;
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Person&>(d);
}
```

Output:

```
I am a doctor
I am a person
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide a definition of `print()` in the `Person` class:

```cpp
class Person {
protected:
    // other stuff...
    virtual void print(ostream& out)  const {
        out << "Doctor: " << name << " " << age << " ";
    }
public:
    // other stuff...
};
// class 'Doctor' follows...
```

Now you can do this:

```cpp
Doctor a;
std::cout << static_cast<Person>(a);
```

Or,

```cpp
Doctor a;
std::cout << Person(a);
```

Or,

```cpp
Doctor a;
Person b = a;
std::cout << b;
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH
Doctor a;
std::cout << Person(a); 
worked

Comment: @TonyMag Note that this creates a copy of the base object. It may not be too bad in this case (you only have one string and one int to to copy), but it's something that needs to be considered.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen So is there a way to not create a copy??

Comment: @TonyMag As far as I know, not without the change of design. By the use of `virtual` keyword you made the `print()` method polymorphic and you cannot stop compiler from doing polymorphic lookup on polymorphic methods. See the other answer for an example of different way to design your code (without virtual methods). But a copy is not always bad. It's just another thing to consider when writing code.